# Java decompiling get duplicated local variables

Tags: java, intellij-idea, decompiler

In a decompiled code by `Intellij IDEA`, I see following code:

```
public void someMethod(Map params)  {
    HashMap params;
    if (null == params) {
        params = new HashMap();
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This code can't compile due to 2 reasons:

- `params` is re-declared in body, thus it's duplicated local variable.
- Even fixed the above issue, the second `params` is still not initialized.

---

### Questions

- Why it decompile in that way?

Comment: It is a bug in the decompiler.  Report it.

Comment: The decompiler in IntelliJ is pretty good in the latest versions, can you try a newer version?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Just checked it with `IDEA community 2019.2`, which is released 10 days ago, it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ uses own decompiler named as "Fernflower". Here is a [GitHub](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower).
It's not a best decompiler but it's an alive, so there is possibility sometimes it will become the best.
Meanwhile you can use Eclipse ;). There is really powerful decompiler [plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enhanced-class-decompiler) which supports several different decompilers.
Also you can use [Jar Explorer](http://dst.in.ua/jarexp/index.html?l=en). This is separate tool which has three decompilers including Fernflower.

Comment: Nice to know tools like `Fernflower` and `Jar Explorer`.